# *Joking* used in continuous form

Tags: progressive-aspect, tenses

"*I'm only joking*" and "*She wasn't joking*". 
Why is the verb *to joke* used in the present continuous, instead of the present simple tense? Is it because it's a dynamic verb?

Comment: I think your examples are referred to the "present continuos" and "past continuos" tenses, not 'dynamic verbs'.

Comment: thanks, but why do we not normally use the past/present simple? "I joke" "She didn't joke".

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. I don't know why two other people have downvoted.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Are you sure you mean [continuos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuo)?

Comment: @Robusto: Argh...! I should have write "continuous".

Comment: Interestingly and conversely, with *jest* the simple form is common: *I jest*, *I jest you not*, *Surely you jest*, etc. At least, this seems to be true in the present tense. In the past tense, the continuous form is more likely: *I was only jesting*, and not *I jested* .

Comment: @Sjb: Well, listen to Bill Maher say "I kid. I kid the president." Not a stretch to say "I joke."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple present vs. present continuous](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65687/simple-present-vs-present-continuous) Though as @Shoe points out, it's intriguing that we're more likely to use present continuous with *"joking"*, but simple present with *"jest"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Sorry, I looked for something similar to what you linked both as "verb" and "verbs" but I missed this question.

Comment: @Paola: I don't normally bother with tags when I search, but with over 700 questions tagged *verbs* (of which *verb* is just a synonym) you'd have a job finding anything with that. Anyway, I just looked for the two words *present* and *continuous* in question text. But in fact the most useful tag here is *progressive-aspect* as added by Carlo *after* you answered.

Answer (score 5):

The past tense typically describes an action at a particular time in the past. So you might expect to hear, for example, *We joked about it at the time, but it was really very serious.*

The past continuous construction makes no such link with a particular time, even though we may know in general terms that the action did take place at a particular time. It emphasises the continuing nature of the action, regardless of how long it actually lasted and may sometimes provide a background to something else happening. For example, *We were joking about the clothes she was wearing when suddenly she walked in.*

In the Madonna incident, *She wasn't joking* describes her continuing state, however short, in reaction to the colour of the room.

Comment: 'Madonna incident'? Which one are you talking about? (which incident that is; I guess you're not referring to Jesus' mom)

Comment: @Mitch: See Sjb's comment on Paola's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I expected to find lots of answers to differenciate Present Simple and Present Continuous, but I've found but a few, and not real duplicates to your question, so I'll try to reply.

According to Michael Swan in his *Practical English Usage*,

> we use the present progressive to talk about temporary actions and situations that are going on now or "around now": before, during and after the moment of speaking.

He also provides the following examples :

Hurry up! We'***re*** all ***waiting*** for you!

"What ***are*** you ***doing***?"  "I ***'m writing*** letters."

He then points out :

> We do not normally use the present progressive to talk about permanent situations, or about things that happen regularly, repeatedly or all the time. Compare :

- Look - the cat'***s eating*** your breakfast!
- What ***do*** bears ***eat***? - Everything.

There's plenty more examples, but I hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Thanks but: Madonna was staying in a Hotel. She asked for a different colour room. "She wasn't joking and they painted the room." What is the most concise explanation for why joking is -ing and painted -ed??  thank you.

Comment: I'd say that, when Madonna requested a different colour room, she *was deadly serious*, hence **not joking**. She might have even threatened the hotel manager to leave the hotel if they did not comply with her request. For this reason, they **painted**  the room a different colour. (And perhaps she **smiled** with satisfaction while they **were painting** it). But is this a real event?

Comment: But in terms of grammar I am a little confused. Would we ever write "She didn't joke". Why not "they were painting the room"

Comment: sorry...thats a little easier to explain, in that we do not want to focus on that process but the decision, as you say. Perhaps you could say the joking was a "background action". But its not convincing to me.

Comment: *She didn't joke* refers to something which happened in the past and so you could find it in sentences such as "She didn't joke (or *didn't use to joke*) much when she was younger, but now her attitude has changed and she's more light-hearted." And "*they were painting*" would be used to talk about the action being performed, whereas *they painted* refers to the consequence or the outcome of Madonna's request.

Comment: yes thanks again, specifically a habit/state/character in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the answer is that *be joking* is functionally a different verb from *joke*.

To *joke* is to perform an action: that of telling a joke, or saying something funny.

To *be joking* is to be in a certain mental state, of intending to make people laugh or (more often) to fool people.

They will often go together, but not always. In particular, if you *joke*, it is usually intended to be obvious to the hearers that that is what you are doing, but if you *are joking* it may or may not be obvious.

So we may take it for granted that Madonna did not *joke* (say something obviously and intentionally funny), but somebody may have thought that she *was joking* (saying something with the intention of amusing or fooling somebody).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. That's a convincing explanation. Only how often do we use joke as a verb in this other sense and how often do we simply make a joke.

Comment: Good point. I think _joke_ in that sense is a little bit formal or literary. Notice also that _joke_ can be used in the continuous ("He was joking and wisecracking all through the journey") but perhaps for the same reason as you mentioned, it's less common.